# BlackBerry Simulator freezes when navigating through browser

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

The BlackBerry Device Simulator v6.0.0.706 (9800) freezes every time I attempt to load a page in the browser.  I'm able to load the browser and go to www.google.com, but loading any other page freezes the entire simulator.  To get back into the simulator, I have to close the window and relaunch.. stopping page load or pressing any of the other buttons in the window does not work.

This is what I have tried:

- Tried loading other web pages to see if the problem persists.
- Tried installing to C:\BlackBerry instead of the default directory in case spaces were an issue.
- Updated to allow full access to all users and my Windows user account.
- Tried running as Administrator.

No error messages display, the simulator just freezes and stays stuck on the same page until I relaunch the simulator.  I am running this on Windows 7.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you running with the MDS simulator, too?

Comment: try any other simulators ?